# How do I prevent my java code from giving me an error message when I don't fill in all of the values for an object in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to create a program that can read a textfile and create an arraylist of objects based off the data (among other things). Most of the text is pretty straight, and is comprised of two double numbers like so:
    454.56 3.4
    3321.7 .0023
However, some of the lines of text are missing a number at the end and only contain one double like this:
    3222.5
This is a simplified version of the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class objectGenerator {
    public double firstDouble;
    public double secondDouble;

    objectGenerator(double 1, double 2) {
        firstDouble = 1;
        secondDouble = 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "data.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " +
                    fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        List<objectGenerator> objects = new ArrayList<objectGenerator>();
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] data = line.split(" ");
            objectGenerator object = new objectGenerator(Double.parseDouble(data[0]), Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
            objects.add(object);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        //example text file
        //544.7 7.4
        //34.5 

    }

}
```

Running the following code will produce an error message due to the fact of how the text file is missing a double at the end of the second line. I am unsure of how to get around this issue and would appreciate any help that I could get.

As a side note, it would be very beneficial if there were some way for me to fill in a default value for the empty space that was left by the text file when I am populating the arraylist. The final text file that I will be working with could potentially contain hundreds of lines of code, so it will be nice if there was a way too fill in a default value for all the empty spaces when I am creating the objects.

Comment: I presume it 's an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. Here's a hint: why don't you instantiate your `objectGenerator` depending on the size of the `data` array?

Comment: Just a try catch would work, no? Or check the length of the split line with an if statement... There are many ways to prevent a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would refactor your `while` loop:

```
static final double DEFAULT_DATA = -1d;   // replace with your desired default value

while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = inputStream.nextLine();
    String[] data = line.split(" ");

    objectGenerator object = null;

    if (data.length == 1 && data[0].equals("")) {  // empty line
        object = new objectGenerator(DEFAULT_DATA, DEFAULT_DATA);
    }
    else if (data.length == 1) {                   // only one number
        object = new objectGenerator(Double.parseDouble(data[0]), DEFAULT_DATA);
    }
    else {                                           // two numbers
        object = new objectGenerator(Double.parseDouble(data[0]),
                                     Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
    }

    // you may want to check if (object == null) here to cover any weird edge cases
    objects.add(object);
}
```

By the way, Java naming conventions state that the first letter of class names should appear in UPPERCASE.  So I would change the name of your class to `ObjectGenerator`, with a capital `O`.

Comment: I fixed the earlier error that I ran into, and now my program is running smoothly! Thank you for the help, and I will be sure to name my classes properly next time.

Answer (score 0):

create overloaded constructor for your `objectGenerator`

```
objectGenerator(double a){
    this(a, 0);
}

objectGenerator(double a, double b){
    firstDouble = a;
    secondDouble = b;
}
```

*I just assumed to keep `secondDouble` value to be zero if not found in text file*

Now you can create `objectGenerator` like this :

```
objectGenerator object = new data.length == 1 ? objectGenerator(Double.parseDouble(data[0])) : new objectGenerator(Double.parseDouble(data[0]),Double.parseDouble(data[1])) ;
```

**if you are using java 8**
You can create constructor with variable arguments

```
objectGenerator(double...arr){
    firstDouble = arr[0];
    secondDouble = arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : 0;
}
```